# I am facing this error "exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, collectionview, exc-bad-instruction

I am running the following code and getting error in swift.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell = Collection_View.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "list", for: indexPath) as! List_CollectionViewCell
     cell.list_name.text = items[indexPath.row]
     **cell.created_date.text = c_date[indexPath.row]**
     return cell
}
```

why is xcode generating this error on this line?

Comment: index out of bounds or unwrapped a nil optional.

Comment: What is in `c_date`? And what is the type of `created_date`?

Comment: ->created_date is the UILabel and i am going to update the text of my UILabel which is an element of CollectionViewCell...                                                                    ->c_date is an array of string through which i am updating my UILabel

Comment: c_date is same count as items arr ?? and label is connected properly

Comment: yup... when item is created its date automatically generated that is why both are of same count

Comment: This exception typically occurs if the outlet in the custom cell is not connected or the class of the cell is not set to the custom class

Comment: Any error message in console when it crashes ?

Comment: Yup......in console I saw "Index out of range"

Answer (score 1):

This error arises when there is a failed force unwrapping. Make sure that the class of the prototype in your storyboard is set to `List_CollectionViewCell` in the Identity Inspector:

[image: class]

and that its identifier is `"list"` in the Attributes inspector:

[image: identifier]